# Google App Engine - NDB - best way of inversing the IN(list)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, fetch, app-engine-ndb

I'm synchronizing data from NDB.

How do I best make a query for all elements, excluding a list of allready found elements - basically inversing the IN(list) operation.

Pseudo-example:

```
found = []
for ele in getElementList():
  ndb_data = ndb.get(ele)
  if ndb_data.is_same_as(ele):
    update(ele)
    found.append(ndb_data.key)
  else:
    delte(ele)
for ele in remaining(found): 
  create(ele)

def remaining(found_list):
  all = Element.query().fetch()
  do_not_want = Element.query(Element.key.IN(found_list)).fetch()
  for ele in all: 
    if ele in do_not_want:
       all.remove(ele)
  return all
```

In other words, can the function remaining(found_list) be made with just a singel fetch - not two with a full loop?

Comment: can't you not simply reverse your *found_list*? Also try not to use `all` as variable as it is a python builtin

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305163/in-ndb-how-to-query-for-items-where-property-a-is-not-in-list-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By constructing a series of 'x!=y AND x!=z' ndb filters, we can emulate a 'NOT IN' query: eg (1):

```
checkList = ['cookieAck', 'newkey', 'tempCelsius']
query = UserSetting.query(Setting.name!=checkList[0])
for check in checkList[1:]:
  query = query.filter(ndb.AND(UserSetting.name!=check))

settings = query.fetch()
```

Practically this looks like the following manually-constructed query (2):

```
  query = UserSetting.query(ndb.AND(ndb.AND(UserSetting.name!='cookieAck', UserSetting.name != 'newkey'), UserSetting.name != 'tempCelsius'))
```

Note that simply doing the following also works (3):

```
query = UserSetting.query(UserSetting.name!='cookieAck', UserSetting.name != 'newkey', UserSetting.name != 'tempCelsius')
```

Resulting Query:

```
Query(kind='UserSetting', filters=OR(AND(FilterNode('name', '<', 'cookieAck'), FilterNode('name', '<', 'newkey'), FilterNode('name', '<', 'tempCelsius')), AND(FilterNode('name', '<', 'cookieAck'), FilterNode('name', '<', 'newkey'), FilterNode('name', '>', 'tempCelsius')), AND(FilterNode('name', '<', 'cookieAck'), FilterNode('name', '>', 'newkey'), FilterNode('name', '<', 'tempCelsius')), AND(FilterNode('name', '<', 'cookieAck'), FilterNode('name', '>', 'newkey'), FilterNode('name', '>', 'tempCelsius')), AND(FilterNode('name', '>', 'cookieAck'), FilterNode('name', '<', 'newkey'), FilterNode('name', '<', 'tempCelsius')), AND(FilterNode('name', '>', 'cookieAck'), FilterNode('name', '<', 'newkey'), FilterNode('name', '>', 'tempCelsius')), AND(FilterNode('name', '>', 'cookieAck'), FilterNode('name', '>', 'newkey'), FilterNode('name', '<', 'tempCelsius')), AND(FilterNode('name', '>', 'cookieAck'), FilterNode('name', '>', 'newkey'), FilterNode('name', '>', 'tempCelsius'))))
```

Note: I have also updated the question linked above.

Comment: This solution may cast "Exceeded soft private memory limit" if looped ~40 times.